# How to add OpenCV repo as a subdirectory in CMake?

Tags: opencv, cmake

I would like to add the [OpenCV source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) as a subdirectory of a CMake project in a parent directory. I can add the OpenCV directory in the parent directory's CMakeLists.txt like this:

```
set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR build)
add_subdirectory(opencv ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

CMake creates a "build" directory in the parent directory, but the OpenCV CMakeLists.txt fails on this check:

```
if(" ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" STREQUAL " ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "
FATAL: In-source builds are not allowed.
       You should create a separate directory for build files.
")
endif()
```

The value of CMAKE_BINARY_DIR is not "build" like I set it in the parent directory; it and CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR are both the parent directory. (I verified this with "message" statements.)

Is there a way to do this without adding or modifying files in the OpenCV source directory?

I'm using CMake version 3.16.3 (on Ubuntu 20.04), but I can upgrade it if need be.

Comment: `set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR build)` - Never set `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`. This variable is intended to point to directory where `cmake` has been called (or directory specified by the parameter `-B`). Just build your project out-of-source (not in the source directory), and the check never triggered. (If you have built your project in-source, then you need to remove `CMakeCache.txt` file for being able to perform out-of-source builds).

Comment: @Tsyvarev - building the project out-of-source is what I'm trying to do with the second parameter to `add_subdirectory`. If I just pass `build` instead of setting `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR`, it still fails the check.

Comment: Build you **main project** out-of-source. So all inner projects (or subprojects) will be built out-of-source automatically.